# Grant "Read all properties” and “Create Computer objects” permissions to a Computer object

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, powershell

Using a Powershell script how do I grant the "Read all properties” and “Create Computer objects” permissions to this Computer object: mylab.com/Computers/Cluster1. The permissions should be granted against this Container: mylab.com/Computers. The net result being that the "Cluster1" computer object should be able to read all properties and create computer objects in its home "Computers" container.

Comment: Look into [Active Directory Delegation of Control Wizard](https://www.google.com/search?q=Active+Directory+Delegation+of+Control+Wizard).

Answer (score 3):

Managed to figure it out:

```
/* Get the GUID that corresponds to Computer objects */

$ComputerGUID = [GUID](Get-ADObject -Filter 'DistinguishedName -eq "CN=Computer,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mylab,DC=com"' -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -prop schemaIDGUID).schemaIDGUID

$Path = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=Computers,DC=mylab,DC=com"
$ntaccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("mylab\cluster1$")
$IdentityReference = $ntaccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

$Perms = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($IdentityReference,"CreateChild","Allow",$ComputerGUID,"All",$([GUID]::Empty))
$Path.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($Perms)

$Perms = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($IdentityReference,"ReadProperty","Allow",$([GUID]::Empty),"All",$([GUID]::Empty))
$Path.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($Perms)

$Path.psbase.commitchanges()

/* Check the results */

(Get-Acl "ad:\CN=Computers,DC=mylab,DC=com").Access | where-object { $_.IdentityReference -eq 'MYLAB\Cluster1$' }

/* Check the returned ObjectType GUID is Computer */

$RawGuid = ([guid]'bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2').toByteArray();
Get-ADObject -Filter {schemaIDGUID -eq $rawGuid} -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -prop schemaIDGUID | Select-Object Name,@{Name='schemaIDGUID';Expression={[guid]$_.schemaIDGUID}}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.